# Attachments in power apps

Tags: powerapps

I try to select more than one attachment in sendmail in power apps but I don't know how. This is the code:

```
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2("miemail@email.com";"Send";"Signs";{Attachments: {Name:"Signs.pdf";ContentBytes:DocPDFExp;Name:"Signs.pdf"; ContentBytes:DocPDFBomb}});;
```